# Problems with call to pandoc in python. Providing "-V args" are not working

Tags: python, pandoc, pypandoc

When I call to pandoc  with "-V args" like for example: '-V title="Wartość"'
in Python script, I get output without title..:(

Example:
Manually typed command to pandoca(in terminal):

```
/usr/bin/pandoc  /home/user/program/content.md -V title="Wartość" 
-V authors="Jerry" --output=/home/user/program/outputs/book_22.pdf
```

It works :)
**output file:**
[pandoc output when use manually pandoc in the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRXL5.jpg)

but when I run the same command in python(call to pandoc):

```
 subprocess.call(['/usr/bin/pandoc', '/home/user/program/content.md', '-V title="Wartość", -V authors="Jerry" ', '--output=/home/user/program/outputs/book_33.pdf'])
```

**output file:** [pandoc output when I call to him from python script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFljm.png)

how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assumption that you are running the "same command" in Python is incorrect.  You have combined arguments into a single string when they should be separate.

```
subprocess.call(['/usr/bin/pandoc', '/home/user/program/content.md',
    '-V',  'title="Wartość"', '-V', 'authors="Jerry"', 
    '--output=/home/user/program/outputs/book_33.pdf'])
```

An easy way to convert a command line to a list suitable for `subprocess.call()` is `shlex.split()`.